# MongoDB Charts JWT authentication issue: JWT providers not matching error

Tags: javascript, mongodb, charts, mongodb-atlas

I'm encountering an issue with MongoDB Charts when using JWT authentication. The charts render properly initially, but when the current token expires and a new token is generated, the chart fails to render, and an error stating "JWT providers are not matching" is displayed. However same token works till next expiry for any attempt afterwards. I am using this [JavaScript SDK](https://unpkg.com/@mongodb-js/charts-embed-dom).

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@mongodb-js/charts-embed-dom"></script>
    function loadChartsEmbedSDK(mongochart, mongoChartFilters) {
        var sdk = new ChartsEmbedSDK({
            baseUrl: mongochart.baseURL,
        });

        var chart = sdk.createChart({
            chartId: mongochart.chartId,
            filter: {
                AddedAtUtc: { $gte: new Date(mongoChartFilters.fromDate), $lte: new Date(mongoChartFilters.toDate) },
                Status: { $in: mongoChartFilters.status },
                CollectionType: { $in: mongoChartFilters.collectionType }
            },
            getUserToken: function () {
                return mongochart.token;
            },
            height: 650,
            width: 700,
            theme: "dark",
            showAttribution: false,
            //maxDataAge: 20
            // Additional options go here
        });
        chart.render(document.getElementById(mongochart.htmlElement));
    }
</script>
```